# SQL - Substraction of 2 Rows in the same Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two value of type longtext in my database that I would like to substract.

Here is the schema:

[image]

I want to substract _store_price by 0.15 and store it in _regular_price to have this result:

[image]

I have really basics knowledge on SQL but I tried to execute this in phpmyadmin without any success:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta AS p1
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS p2
ON p1.post_id = 30860
SET p1.meta_value = CAST( CAST( p2.meta_value as DECIMAL(10,2)) - 0.15 ) as char(20))
WHERE p1.meta_key = '_regular_price'
AND p2.meta_key = '_store_price'
```

Does any one has an idea of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need 2 queries, because they are on 2 rows and you need to "align" them to perform the update on just one of those rows.

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta AS p1
SET p1.meta_value = (
  SELECT CAST((CAST(p2.meta_value AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) - 0.15) AS CHAR(20))
  FROM (
   SELECT *
   FROM wp_postmeta
   ) AS p2
  WHERE p2.post_id = 30860 AND p2.meta_key = '_prix_magasin'
  )
WHERE p1.post_id = 30860 AND p1.meta_key = '_regular_price'
;
```

For a updating a larger number of values then use an inner join but setup the join conditions so that the 2 meta_key rows are now aligned together

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta AS p1
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS p2 ON p1.post_id = p2.post_id
                            AND p1.meta_key = '_regular_price'
                            AND p2.meta_key = '_prix_magasin'
SET p1.meta_value = CAST( (CAST( p2.meta_value as DECIMAL(10,2)) - 0.15 ) as char(20))

## example only
## where p1.post_id IN(30860,30861,30862,30863 ...)
;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=83f66fa848983e437ca3d4f873ec0039)*

Comment: I had to modify it like this to make it work:

​
UPDATE wp_postmeta AS p1
SET p1.meta_value =
(SELECT CAST( (CAST( p2.meta_value AS DECIMAL(10,2)) - 0.15 ) AS CHAR(20))
FROM (SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta) AS p2 WHERE p2.post_id = 30860 AND p2.meta_key = '_prix_magasin')
WHERE p1.post_id = 30860 AND p1.meta_key = '_regular_price'

Comment: Now imagine, I want to do it for all records in the table and not only on that specific post_id, how will you do it?

Comment: Don't know if I can still add a comment but I am trying to update the '_regular_price' p1.meta_value only if the '_store_price' p2.meta_value is NOT empty, but it stills get updated. Any ideas why?

UPDATE wp_postmeta AS p1
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS p2 ON p1.post_id = p2.post_id AND p1.meta_key = '_regular_price' AND p2.meta_key = '_store_price'
SET p1.meta_value = CAST((CAST(p2.meta_value AS DECIMAL(10,2)) - (CAST(p2.meta_value AS DECIMAL(10,2)) * 0.02)) AS CHAR(20))
WHERE p2.meta_value != ''

Answer (score 0):

The `ON` condition in the `JOIN` needs to relate the rows in the two tables. It should be used to specify that they're both for the same `post_id`. Use the `WHERE` clause for conditions on each table by itself.

And use `INNER JOIN` unless you need to handle the case where there's no match in the second table.

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta AS p1
JOIN wp_postmeta AS p2 ON p1.post_id = p2.post_id
SET p1.meta_value = p2.meta_value - 0.15
WHERE p1.meta_key = '_regular_price'
AND p2.meta_key = '_store_price'
AND p1.post_id = 30860
```